# Are there any Linux Distros /DEs that support independant workspaces on multi monitors similar to Mac

Tags: linux, desktop-environment

I am Looking for behaviour similar to a Mac's DE.
I want to be able to switch workspaces independantly of the monitors. A lot of people have suggested setting `workspaces-only-on-primary` to `false` however, this just enables the same workspace on multiple monitors i.e when I try to switch the workspace on my main display, it also changes the workspace on my monitor.

Expected Behavior:

- When changing the workspace on one monitor (e.g., the primary monitor), the other monitor(s) should remain on their current workspace.
- Each monitor should operate independently in terms of workspace management.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that's a pretty normal feature in a lot of window managers.

I'm using `awesomewm` as a daily driver, and in the default configuration, workspaces on different screens are completely independent from each other.